# Изменение папки приложения в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть 2 приложения (frontend и backend). Сейчас мне надо добавить еще несколько и хочу их засунуть в одну папку, чтобы получилась такая структура:

```
-components
-console
-environments
-...
-modules
----frontend
----backend
----common
----new_app1
----...
```

Как лучше это реализовать?
Пробовал вносить изменения в Bootstrap.php:

```
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/modules/frontend');
```

Но это не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужно по модулям разбить можно сделать так:

*у файле конфиге*:

```
'modules' => [
    'api' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\api\v1\module',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\admin\admin',
    ],
],
```

Сделано подключения двух модулей в Yii2

Структура:

```
-components
-console
-environments
-...
-modules
----api
----admin
----...
```